# Catch some of user action in system android

Tags: android

Is this possible to catch event from system in my application? I want to get event that user click on send in messages. I want to write application which will block some functions of system like send sms, mms etc. Is this possible?

Comment: across the board? all phones all apps? no, not without root.

Comment: you can use Broadcast Receivers to get events, and block some of them, like get sms